# Understanding AngularJS testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner

I seem to be unable to wrap my head around the concept of testing AngularJS applications.

I use PHPstorm as my IDE and have successfully installed node.js aswell as karma through node.

I have then created a karma.config file:

```
  module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
  basePath: '',
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  files: [
      'js/angular.js',
      'js/va.angular.js',
    'test/**/**/*Spec.js'
  ],
  exclude: [

  ],
  reporters: ['progress'],
  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: false,
  browsers: ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'],
  captureTimeout: 60000,
  singleRun: false
});
};
```

I have also created a test file:

```
// mainSpec.js
describe('controllers', function(){
beforeEach(angular.module('va'));

it('should friggin test something', inject(function() {
    var x = 5;
    expect(x.toBe(5));
}));
});
```

However, as i try to run my test, it fails due to:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
TypeError: Object 5 has no method 'toBe'
```

Now i have 2 questions:

- What am i doing wrong here?
- Where does the karma stuff get the jasmine stuff from? To me it looks like it can't get it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're including the `angular-mocks.js` module in your list of files to load.

When you specify `frameworks: ['jasmine']` in the karma config, it includes jasmine so there's no need to include it yourself.

As for your error,

```
expect(x.toBe(5))
```

should be:

```
expect(x).toBe(5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much so far!
Would you mind to briefly explain what said angular-mocks.js is used for and where i can find a template for it?

Comment: angular-mocks is a set of functionalities that are used to mock different components of angular. For instance, if you want to test whether the data returned from your server is being correctly filled in in your object, you mock the `$http` service and make it return a dummy data without having to call your actual web service. This might help you understand testing http://www.benlesh.com/2013/05/angularjs-unit-testing-controllers.html

Comment: Thanks again. I included it, and also solved the error on toBe(), but am still getting one for apply()

Comment: Instead of using `angular.module`, either use `angular.mock.module` or just simply `module` (`angular.mock.module` places itself on the window object for convenience).

Comment: You are probably calling $scope.apply() instead of $scope.$apply() and the test is catching that error for you.